# Grails database action and view rendering

Tags: grails, groovy, controller, gsp

I'm trying to add a simple functionality to my Grails project that similarily to youtube will allow users to like/unlike an article. There's a very primitive page to display articles with their likes and a controller that makes 'liking' possible. Alas, whenever this method is called, it tries to render an unexisting view instead of coming back to the previous one. Here's the .gsp body code:

```
<g:each in="${articles}" var="article">
        <table class="table-bordered">
            <tr>Article title: ${article.title}</tr><br>
            <tr>Author: ${article.author}</tr><br>
            <tr>Page: ${article.page}</tr><br>
            <tr>Likes: ${article.getLikesCount()}</tr><br>
            <g:link resource="Article" action="articleLiked" id="${article.id}" params="[articleId: article.id]">Like it!</g:link>
        </table>
    </g:each>
```

And this is my controller's 'like' method code:

```
def articleLiked(Article article){
        ServiceUser user = springSecurityService.currentUser
        ArticleLike al = ArticleLike.findByArticleAndServiceUser(article, user)
        if(al){
            al.liked = true
        }else{
            al = new ArticleLike(Article: article, ServiceUser: user, liked: true)
        }
        al.save()
        showArticleList()
    }
```

As a result, I've got this exception:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI
    /article/articleLiked/1
Class
    javax.servlet.ServletException
Message
    Could not resolve view with name '/article/articleLiked' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
```

Also, even after I manually go back to the articleList page, the value of `getLikesCount()` method output is still 0. What's causing all this trouble?

**UPDATE:**

Just in case you were wondering, my showArticleList() method looks like this:

```
def showArticleList(){
        render (view: 'articleList',  model: [ articles: getArticle(), articleLikes: getArticleLike()]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the problem. I've changed the Article declaration line to

```
Article article = Article.findById(params.getIdentifier())
```

and what is more, the problem was also within my `if-else` - I've been creating new ArticleLike object by using types as arguments instead of field names declared in my Domain class, so it should be

```
}else{
            al = new ArticleLike(article: article, serviceUser: user, liked: true)
        }
```

instead of

```
else{
                al = new ArticleLike(Article: article, ServiceUser: user, liked: true)
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things ,

```
def articleLiked(){

ServiceUser user = springSecurityService.currentUser
Article article = Article.get(params.id)
ArticleLike al = ArticleLike.findByArticleAndServiceUser(article, user)

// the rest of your code
```

And you should use redirect if you want to redirect to another action. so change `showArticleList()` to `redirect(action:  "showArticleList")`
`}`
That should work.

Comment: thanks for answer. it still doesn't work tough, the exception isn't showing anymore, but for some reason nothing is added to the `ArticleLike` database table. I think there's a problem with passing parameters to method - I've created `debugStuff()` that should print multiple empty lines when `articleLiked()` is called, but it's not happening. It looks like the method isn't invoked at all

Comment: what idea are you using?  You don't need to create any method to debug this. Couldn't you just put a breakpoint ?

Comment: cause sometimes its faster to look on the console than clicking and finding variables. ive been using debugger as well